# Add Fields to Csv with Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

So, I have a CSV which contains spatial (`latitude`, `longitude`) and temporal (`timestamp`) data.

To be useful for us, we converted the spatial information to  "`geohash`", and the temporal information to "`timehash`".

The problem is, how to add the `geohash` and `timehash` as fields for each row in the CSV with spark (since the data is about **200 GB**)?

we tried to use `JavaPairRDD` and it's function `mapTopair` , but the problem remains in how to convert back to a `JavaRdd` and then to CSV? So i think this was a bad solution I'm asking for a simple way.

## Update of question :

After @Alvaro is  help i have created this java class :

```
public class Hash {
public static SparkConf Spark_Config;
public static JavaSparkContext Spark_Context;

UDF2 geohashConverter = new UDF2<Long, Long, String>() {
    
    public String call(Long latitude, Long longitude) throws Exception {
        // convert here
        return "calculate_hash";
    }
};

UDF1 timehashConverter = new UDF1<Long, String>() {
    
    public String call(Long timestamp) throws Exception {
        // convert here
        return "calculate_hash";
    }
};
public Hash(String path) {
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("Java Spark SQL Example")
            .config("spark.master", "local")
            .getOrCreate();
    
    spark.udf().register("geohashConverter", geohashConverter, DataTypes.StringType);
    spark.udf().register("timehashConverter", timehashConverter, DataTypes.StringType);
    
Dataset df=spark.read().csv(path)
    .withColumn("geohash", callUDF("geohashConverter", col("_c6"), col("_c7")))
    .withColumn("timehash", callUDF("timehashConverter", col("_c1")))
.write().csv("C:/Users/Ahmed/Desktop/preprocess2");

 }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String path = "C:/Users/Ahmed/Desktop/cabs_trajectories/cabs_trajectories/green/2013";
    Hash h = new Hash(path);
}
}
```

and then i get serialization problem, which disappear when i delete `write().csv()`

Comment: Can you share some snippet so that we can see how you are currently loading the CSV?

Comment: you need to know how i m loading the csv in spark ??!!

Comment: I just wanted to see whether you are using the Datasets Spark API or just creating and RDD reading the file line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most efficient ways is to load the CSV using the Datasets API and use User Defined Function to convert the columns you've specified. In this way, your data will always remain structure, not having to deal with tuples.

First of all, you create your User Define Functions: `geohashConverter`, which takes two values (`latitude` and `longitude`), and `timehashConverter`, which only takes the timestamp.

```
UDF2 geohashConverter = new UDF2<Long, Long, String>() {
    @Override
    public String call(Long latitude, Long longitude) throws Exception {
        // convert here
        return "calculate_hash";
    }
};

UDF1 timehashConverter = new UDF1<Long, String>() {
    @Override
    public String call(Long timestamp) throws Exception {
        // convert here
        return "calculate_hash";
    }
};
```

Once created, you have to register them:

```
spark.udf().register("geohashConverter", geohashConverter, DataTypes.StringType);
spark.udf().register("timehashConverter", timehashConverter, DataTypes.StringType);
```

And finally, just read your CSV file, and apply the User Defined Functions by calling the `withColumn`. It will create a new column based on the User Defined Function you are calling with `callUDF`. `callUDF` always receives a String with the name of the registered UDF you want to call and one or many Columns whose value will be passed to the UDF.

And finally, just save your dataset by calling `write().csv("path")`

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.callUDF;


spark.read().csv("/source/path")
        .withColumn("geohash", callUDF("geohashConverter", col("latitude"), col("longitude")))
        .withColumn("timehash", callUDF("timehashConverter", col("timestamp")))
.write().csv("/path/to/save");
```

Hope it helped!

### Update

It would be pretty helpful if you post the code which is causing problems, because the exception says almost nothing about what part of the code is not serializable.

Anyways, from my personal experience with Spark, I think the problem is the object you are using to caculate the hashes. Bear in mind that this object has to be distributed through the cluster. If this object cannot be serialized, it will throw a `Task not serializable Exception`. You have two options to work around it:

- Implement the `Serializable` interface in the class that you use to calculate the hash.
- Create an static method that generate the hashes and call this method from the UDF.

### Update 2

> and then i get serialization problem, which disappear when i delete
>   write().csv()

It's an expected behaviour. When you delete `write().csv()` you are executing nothing. You should know how Spark works. In this code, all the methods called before `csv()` are transformations. In Spark, transformation are not executed until an action like `csv()`, `show()` or `count()` is called.

The problem is that you are creating and executing the Spark Job in a non-serializable class (and even worst in a constructor!!!??)

Creating the Spark job in an static method solves the problem. Bear in mind that your Spark code must be distributed through the cluster, and consequently, it must be serializable. It worked for me and must work for you:

```
public class Hash {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = "in/prueba.csv";

        UDF2 geohashConverter = new UDF2<Long, Long, String>() {

            public String call(Long latitude, Long longitude) throws Exception {
                // convert here
                return "calculate_hash";
            }
        };

        UDF1 timehashConverter = new UDF1<Long, String>() {

            public String call(Long timestamp) throws Exception {
                // convert here
                return "calculate_hash";
            }
        };

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Java Spark SQL Example")
                .config("spark.master", "local")
                .getOrCreate();

        spark.udf().register("geohashConverter", geohashConverter, DataTypes.StringType);
        spark.udf().register("timehashConverter", timehashConverter, DataTypes.StringType);

        spark
                .read()
                .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                .option("header", "true")
                .load(path)
                .withColumn("geohash", callUDF("geohashConverter", col("_c6"), col("_c7")))
                .withColumn("timehash", callUDF("timehashConverter", col("_c1")))
                .write().csv("resultados");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help,but my java compiler can't recognize  'col()',did it need a specific import.

Comment: Try It: `import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;`

Comment: Another question  the attributes of **callUDF** aren't clear i can't find explanation in [the doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html)

Comment: The `callUDF` always receives a String with the name of the registered UDF you want to call and one or many Columns whose value will be passed to the UDF.

Comment: i get serialization problem i will update my question

Comment: that works fine , thank you so much for your effort i appreciate that